# react-native-localization android problem

Tags: javascript, react-native

When user presses on changeLocale button this error happens and the app is crashing.

[image]

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Homepage.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        locale: {},
        token: '',
    };

    this._changeLocale = this._changeLocale.bind(this);
}

_changeLocale() {

    if(this.state.locale.short === 'TR') {

        changeLocale({id: 2, short: 'EN'}, this.state.token);
        this.setState({
            locale: {id: 2, short: 'EN'}
        })
    } else {
        changeLocale({id: 1, short: 'TR'}, this.state.token);
        this.setState({
            locale: {id: 1, short: 'TR'}
        })
    }

}

renderContent() {

    return(
        <Container style={styles.container}>

            <HomepageHeader _changeLocale={this._changeLocale} locale={this.state.locale} />
        ...
        </Container>
}
```

HomepageHeader.js

```
render() {

    return(

        <Header style={styles.header} androidStatusBarColor={'#243f65'}>
         ...

            <Right style={styles.right}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => {this.props._changeLocale()}}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>{this.props.locale.short}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Right>

        </Header>
    );
}
```

Function.js

```
export function changeLocale(locale, token) {

Variables.LOCALE.setLanguage(locale.short);

AsyncStorage.setItem('locale', JSON.stringify(locale));

return axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Variables.API_URL + 'auth/changeLocale',
    data: {
        locale_id: locale.id
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
});
```

}

Variables.js

```
static LOCALE = new LocalizedStrings({
    TR: {
        pages: {
            invitation: 'Davet',
            boards: 'Kurullar',
            program: 'Bilimsel Program',
            accommodation: 'Kayıt & Konaklama',
            courses: 'Kurslar',
            general: 'Genel Bilgiler',
            contact: 'İletişim',
            live: 'Canlı',
            papers: 'Bildiriler',
            search: 'Ara',
            speakers: 'Konuşmacılar',
            favorites: 'Favoriler'
        },
    },
    EN: {
        pages: {
            invitation: 'Invitation',
            boards: 'Boards',
            program: 'Scientific Program',
            accommodation: 'Registration & Accommodation',
            courses: 'Courses',
            general: 'General Information',
            contact: 'Contact',
            live: 'Live',
            papers: 'Papers',
            search: 'Search',
            speakers: 'Speakers',
            favorites: 'Favorites'
        }
    }
});
```

So basically i want to press a button to change the localization of project which is in Variables.js file.

I was able to do it my previous projects but in this, i can not manage it.

I think that the problem might have been occur because of Android API level. I just read this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/improvingux#use-android-ripple

But still i have no solutions.

Comment: You might want to post the codes for changing language as it would help people to understand the issue.

Comment: I've just edited my question with codes. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment does the texts actually shows? According to the react-native-localization site, there's no object within the 'en', and the language code seems to be lower-caps.

Comment: texts don't display at the screen. actually nothing displays. when i press the changeLocale button this error page occurs and app crashes.

Comment: I think you may need to remove the object "pages" and just have the strings objects instead (at least that seems to be the way the site shows) and try changing the language code to lower caps as well just in case